# Tablesorter filter Function Distorts Table Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

When doing searches or filter to specific name if there are multiple results the table becomes distorted, see images showing table before filter and after filter:
[image: How it looks before filter]

[image: how it looks after filter]

Here is the code i am using:

```
    <div class="pager">
    <img src="../assets/images/first.png" class="first" alt="First" />
    <img src="../assets/images/previous.png" class="prev" alt="Prev" />
    <span class="pagedisplay"></span> <!-- this can be any element, including an input -->
    <img src="../assets/images/next.png" class="next" alt="Next" />
    <img src="../assets/images/last.png" class="last" alt="Last" />
    <select class="pagesize" title="Select page size">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
    </select>
    <select class="gotoPage" title="Select page number"></select>
</div>

<table class="tablesorter">
<colgroup>
    <col width="85" />
    <col width="155" />
    <col width="155" />
    <col width="100" />
    <col width="100" />
</colgroup>
```

Here is the javascript:

```js
$(function() {

  $(".tablesorter")
    .tablesorter({
      theme: 'blue',
      // this is the default setting
      cssChildRow: "tablesorter-childRow",

      // initialize zebra and filter widgets
      widgets: ["zebra", "filter", "pager"],

      widgetOptions: {
        // output default: '{page}/{totalPages}'
        // possible variables: {page}, {totalPages}, {filteredPages}, {startRow}, {endRow}, {filteredRows} and {totalRows}
        pager_output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} ({totalRows})', // '{page}/{totalPages}'
        pager_removeRows: false,


        // include child row content while filtering, if true
        filter_childRows: true,
        // class name applied to filter row and each input
        filter_cssFilter: 'tablesorter-filter',
        // search from beginning
        filter_startsWith: false,
        // Set this option to false to make the searches case sensitive
        filter_ignoreCase: true
      }

    });

  // hide child rows
  $('.tablesorter-childRow td').hide();

  // Toggle child row content (td), not hiding the row since we are using rowspan
  // Using delegate because the pager plugin rebuilds the table after each page change
  // "delegate" works in jQuery 1.4.2+; use "live" back to v1.3; for older jQuery - SOL
  $('.tablesorter').delegate('.toggle', 'click', function() {

    // use "nextUntil" to toggle multiple child rows
    // toggle table cells instead of the row
    $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr.tablesorter-hasChildRow').find('td').toggle();

    return false;
  });

  // Toggle widgetFilterChildRows option
  $('button.toggle-option').click(function() {
    var c = $('.tablesorter')[0].config.widgetOptions,
      o = !c.filter_childRows;
    c.filter_childRows = o;
    $('.state').html(o.toString());
    // update filter; include false parameter to force a new search
    $('table').trigger('search', false);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Table HTML

```
            <tr>
<td rowspan="5"> <!-- rowspan="5" makes the table look nicer -->
    <a href="#" class="toggle">[[+id]] - More info</a> <!-- link to toggle view of the child row -->
</td>
<td>[[+deptown]]</td>
<td>[[+arrtown]]</td>
<td>[[+freightdate]]</td>
<td>[[+cubmt]]</td>
        </tr>
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow"><td colspan="4"><div class="bold">Vehicle Type</div><div>[[+vehicletype]]<br></div></td></tr>
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow"><td colspan="4"><div class="bold">Job Details</div><div>[[+freightvehicledetail]]<br></div></td></tr>
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow"><td colspan="4"><div class="bold">Contact Details</div><div>[[+freightvehiclecontact]]<br></div></td></tr>
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow"><td colspan="4"><div class="bold">Expected Rate in RM</div><div>[[+returnrate]]<br></div></td></tr>
```

I got 2 questions:

1. How do I get the search to show clean undistorted results where just click on 'more info' will reveal child data?
2. What change do I make to get 100 results to appear by default?

I just want to add, when table first loads it only displays 20 results.

Comment: It seems like the problem might be in the table HTML, could you please include that in your question.

Comment: Hi Mottie, I just added the table html into the question as requested

Comment: link to see [table](http://bit.ly/1JhXxpp) in its webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the problem is that the `colspan` is set to 4 when it should be set to 5

```
<td colspan="5">...</td>
```

I copied the HTML into [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yfwwzvL8/106/), and it appears to work without any issues.

To get 100 results to show by default, set the widget options (since you're using the pager widget) [`pager_size` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-size) to `100`.

```
// set number of rows to show; make sure to include this
// value in the select options
pager_size: 100,
```

Also, include this option in the select within the pager HTML

```
<select class="pagesize" title="Select page size">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

**As a reminder**: the [`pager_savePages` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#save-pages) is set to `true` by default, so it saves the last setting of the page size to local/session storage,
so changing the default setting to `100` **may not appear to work** until you manually set the page size select to `100`!! Or clear the local/session storage.

Comment: Hi Mottie, yes that worked a treat :-) Thank you for providing this solution.